# Release build loading cached files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

For a reason unknown to me, the Release version of my application has started loading cached static files.

If i build in debug mode all is well and it loads the correct most recent files, this occurs on the device and inside the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean all. I don't remember how to get to it in the menus, but I do it often enough I have the keyboard shortcut ingrained. With no debugger running (hit "stop" if you have to), do Cmd-Shift-K. You'll get a confirm dialog asking for the depth of "clean" to do, and take it up on a full cleaning.

That'll delete all cached objects and the next "build and run" will build all targets from scratch, including updated images and nibs that it hasn't been getting fresh.

Answer (score 1):

Try going in the menu to XCode -> Empty Caches

Comment: hmm didn't fix the problem, handy feature though didn't know that existed

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by deleting the resources in xcode and also moving the files to trash, then adding them back into the project. Would be nice to find a way to stop this from happening in the future though.